# Catalan Number recursive in Scala

Tags: java, scala, recursion, numbers, recursive-datastructures

I know how to calculate the Catalan Number in java, which is pretty straight forward:

```
int catalan(int n) {
    int res = 0;

    // Base case
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res += catalan(i) * catalan(n - i - 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```

But I can't imagine how to do this in Scala, because I'm totally new to it.
Is it possible to do this without the use of var ?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
object Catalan {

  def catalan: Int => Int = n => {
    val res = 0
    val i = 0

    if (n <= 1) 1 
    else for (i <- 0 to n-1) res += catalan(i) * catalan(n - i - 1)
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
def catalan(n: Int): Int = 
  if (n <= 1) 1 
  else (0 until n).map(i => catalan(i) * catalan(n - i - 1)).sum
```

Here I do the same as your java-implementation, but instead of a var I use a range (0 until n) and uses that to create a sum.

The implementation performance could benefit heavily from memoization.

Comment: +1 A generic way to memoize functions such as this can be found at: https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/Memo.scala

Also, other identities for the Catalan numbers could be used, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number.

Comment: Funny how that code links straight back to stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: In the net graph stackoverflow and github should be heavily connected one would expect :-)

Comment: It'd be useful if it were tail recursive.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `fold` instead of `res +=` piece and the rest of logic is the same as in your java algorithm:

```
def catalan(n: Int): Int = {
      if (n <= 1) 1
      else (0 until n).fold(0)((acc, i) => acc + catalan(i) * catalan(n - i - 1))
}
```